# What is the importance of the speed of sound in our day-to-day life?

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, acoustics

The speed of sound is mentioned everywhere but, despite studying so much, I still don't understand the importance of the figure and how it has had its impacts on the real world.

Comment: For one thing, it’s why commercial planes don’t fly faster than they do.

Comment: Knowing how far away the thunderstorm is helps in the backcountry.

Comment: Welcome to PSE! In general, opinion-based and list-based questions are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Questions should have one correct answer.

Comment: While it may not fit the kind of questions we answer, it is still a good question with interesting answers.

Comment: It certainly has an effect on communication with other humans, it would be a strange world if sound was a lot slower

Answer (score 4):

The comments below your question already list some features:

- [Supersonic airplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersonic_aircraft) require much higher and more
  expensive technology than subsonic airplanes. That's why
  passenger airplanes fly slower than sound.
- In thunderstorms the speed of sound is the reason why we hear
  the [thunder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunder#Perception) some seconds after we see the lightining.

I would like to add some more features from daily life:

- The loud sound of a [whip-crack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whipcracking#Physics) is actually a sonic boom
  created by the fast moving end of the whip.
- Because of the speed of sound there is a time-difference of less
  than a millisecond between sounds reaching our left and right ear
  depending from where the sound comes.
  See [How Our Ears Sense the Direction of Sounds](https://ehomerecordingstudio.com/binaural-hearing/)
  (section "1. Variations in Timing").
- In wind instruments (flute, trumpet, saxophone, organ, ...)
  the speed of sound together with the length of the pipe
  determines the pitch of the sound. See [Flute acoustics](https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/fluteacoustics.html).

Comment: Also:  communicating with divers breathing Helium-Oxygen mixtures...